# How to Create user attribute in keycloak by admin-cli

Tags: keycloak

I tried following command to create user attributes but nothing working

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create users/b33088e5-321e-4b2f-afa6-7dca1871084e/user-attributes -r master -s name=user-attributes -s 'config."appid"=["APP_ID"]'  -s 'config."tenantId"=["T0"]' -s 'config."ugId"=["Admin_UserGroup"]'
```

Error

> Resource not found for url:
>   https://135.250.45.68:8666/auth/admin/realms/master/users/b33088e5-321e-4b2f-afa6-7dca1871084e/user-attributes

Next i tried this command

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create components -r master -s name=user-attribute -s providerId=user-attribute -s parentId=1295a70f-25f7-4e45-bcb8-285d750 1c6d9 -s 'config."appid"=["APP_ID"]'  -s 'config."tenantId"=["T0"]' -s 'config."ugId"=["Admin_UserGroup"]'
```

End with following error

> HTTP error - 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After too many hit & try,also with the help of my teammate we found the solution and we have to fire below command through admin-cli to create user attributes

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create users  -s username=admin111 -s enabled=true -r master -s "attributes.tenantId=value" -s "attributes.ugId=ugId" -s "attributes.appId=app"
```